# Camunda Email approval workflow

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, camunda-plugin

I would like to create an Approval email workflow in camunda 7.
It should follow these steps:

- send the email to the approver
- check if the email has been approved or not

  - if it hasn't been approved for 2 days, do another flow..

I'm not a java developer / I'm still learning camunda. It would be a bit hard to write a custom plugin for me.. is there another option or an existing plugin?

Thanks.